# how to make struct member pointer in assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, macros, struct

I'm trying to create a macro which would make easier to point to a structs member. Currently I am pointing to a structs member in assembly file using the `STRUCT_NAME + offset` method.

For example if I want to point structs third member, I would have to do it like this:

```
STRUCT_NAME + 3
```

This seems stupid way to do it, and if I insert more members in the struct, I have to update all the offset values in the code.

Is there a way to point using `STRUCT_NAME + macro(struct_name, member_name)`?

I`m using texas instruments TMS320C28x hardware.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler should have the `offsetof` macro, not sure if you can use that from within inline-assembly though.